# How can I prevent an rbash escape using Control-C

Tags: security, bash

I have assigned an account the login shell `/bin/rbash` and have found a vulnerability that seems to render `rbash` largely useless.

The account's `.bash_login` just runs `.bashrc`:

```
. $HOME/.bashrc
```

and `.bashrc` sets `PATH` to a directory containing the only permissible commands:

```
PATH=/restrict/bin
```

This nominally works. However, I find that if I `ssh` into the account and hit Control-C almost instantaneously after entering the password, there is a modest chance (maybe one in five) that `rbash` is interrupted and drops to the shell prompt before running `.bashrc`, whereupon `PATH` has not been changed and the user ends up with unfettered access to `/bin`.

Please tell me I'm missing something, because a solution seems difficult short of actually fixing and recompiling `bash`. I'm also wary of the long list of specific behaviors `rbash` modifies to obtain "security". I would abandon `bash` for this purpose, except that `bash` scripting is firmly ingrained with my users.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to set the path in the `.bash_login` file, completely skipping loading it from `.bashrc`

**EDIT**:

After coming back and looking at this, I realized that just simply setting the `$PATH` variable does not actually accomplish anything as the user can just change it to include other directories that include binaries that are *restricted* in the sense you are taking about, nor does it prevent directly calling the executable. In POSIX compliant shells, you can set a variable as readonly (`readonly PATH=/restricted/bin`). To then solve the later, you would then have to restrict the user / group to not access other bin files / folders.

Comment: The fallowing are prohibited in rbash * Setting or unsetting the values of the 'SHELL', 'PATH', 'ENV', or
      'BASH_ENV' variables.
    * Specifying command names containing slashes." . So you cann't directly change the PATH once set or execute anything not on that path. If this were not the case rbash would useless as merely typing /bin/sh would get a full working shell.